# checking for repeated input of coordinates by the user MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, error-handling, user-input, error-checking

Can anyone help me write the code to check if the user entered the same coordinate twice?

part of the code:

```
rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
              row = rc(1); %users coordinates 
              col = rc(2);
                           if row<0 || col<0
                           disp('Please enter positive coordinates');
                           rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
                           row = rc(1); 
                           col = rc(2);
                           end
                           if row>size || col>size
                           disp('Please enter cordinates with in the game board');
                           rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
                           row = rc(1);
                           col = rc(2);
                           end
```

I have allready checked for positive and too large of values, but now i want to check to make sure the user does not enter the same coordinate twice, and if they do show an error message. 
Any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: I strongly suggest replacing the `if` statements with `while` loops, otherwise you are allowing the end user to crash your program. Would you like to display an [`error`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) message to interrupt the program, or request user [`input`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) like you are already doing? They are different things.

Comment: oh i see, I would like to request user input again after the user enters a repeat coordinate. and for the while loops, would i do: while row<0||col<0 and so on?

Comment: Exactly. Do you want to request user input if the user repeats `row || col` or `row && col`? By the way, are you familiar with the `==` operator?

Comment: So the user repeatedly enters coordinates so i would need to save the entered coordinates and check each new coordinate against the ones already entered, and yes it would be row&&col

Comment: Alright, you are now ready to turn your words into code. If you store the entered coordinates in an array, it should be pretty straightforward. You can edit your question and update your progress.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comment section, to make sure that the user does not enter the same coordinates twice, you should store every pair of valid coordinates in arrays, so that the next time the user enters a new pair of coordinates, you can check if they already exist.

I created two arrays: `rowv` for the `row` coordinates and `colv` for the `col` coordinates.

Then I implemented the following `while` condition using the [logical operators](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html) `any` and `&`, combined with the `==` [relational operator](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-comparison-with-relational-operators.html):

```
% Check that the point is not repeated.
while any((rowv == row) & (colv == col))
```

So as long as the user enters repeated coorinates he/she will be asked to try again until a valid pair is entered.

The following code is a full working example, so you can test it right away:

```
% Game board size.
size = 4;

% Ask for number of points.
n = input('Number of points: ');

% Preallocate arrays with -1.
rowv = -ones(1,n);
colv = -ones(1,n);

% Iterate as many times as points.
for p = 1:n
    % Ask for point coordinates.
    rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
    row = rc(1);
    col = rc(2);

    % Check that coordinates are positive.
    while row<0 || col<0
        disp('Please enter positive coordinates');
        rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
        row = rc(1);
        col = rc(2);
    end

    % Check that coordinates are within the game board.
    while row>size || col>size
        disp('Please enter cordinates within the game board');
        rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
        row = rc(1);
        col = rc(2);
    end

    % Check that the point is not repeated.
    while any((rowv == row) & (colv == col))
        disp('Coordinates already exist. Please enter a new pair of cordinates');
        rc = input('Enter your next move [row space column]: ');
        row = rc(1);
        col = rc(2);
    end

    % The point is valid.
    % Store coordinates in arrays.
    rowv(p) = rc(1);
    colv(p) = rc(2);
end
```